# How to insert a missing element or modify an existing element?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am working on XML & XSLT dynamic value has to generate.

My XmL

```
<query>
     <one>testing1</one>
     <one>testing1</one>
</query>
```

My Output Xml

```
<query>
     <one>testing1</one>
     <one>testing1</one>
     <sample>100</sample>
</query>
```

XSLT
I need to check(XSL:IF)whether sample element is available or not from Input XML if available 10% I have to remove % using XSLT then output will be 10.  If there Is no element in XML(Sample) It has to create by default 100.

Can we able to do this in XSLT is that possible.

Can anyone help me out here please

Regards
M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*[not(//sample)]">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     <sample>100</sample> 
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sample">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'%','')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Explanation

The second template adds the sample node, if it was not present.
The third template removes any percentage signs from existing samples.

Comment: hi @Sean thanks for the reply is that possible with the help of xsl:if condition can we do it instead having this many lines..........

Comment: Maybe. But it would be awkward and unnecessary. I'll let some other answer poster come up with an xsl:if alternative.

Comment: @maha: It is a good practice *not* to use explicit XSLT conditional instructions. It is in the spirit of XSLT to use templates and match-patterns instead. The benefits of this principle are: extensibility, much easier maintainability, readability, robustness, not so error-prone than when using explicit conditionals. The "if() then ... else ..." thinking is a remnant of the days of imperative programming -- one needs to make the leap to the functional programming paradigm -- a whole new way of thinking that frees the imagination -- to fully utilize the power of XSLT.

Comment: Thank you very much Sean & Dimitre i got it.

Comment: Hi Dimitre & Sean can you please tell me how to use path(XSLT) for the above question please guide me here. Thank you very much

Comment: @maha: I think that Sean provided a good explanation in his answer. If you have new questions, please, ask them as questions because the comments format isn't convenient for sharing code.

Comment: @maha: Please don't edit my answer, especially with unrelated information. It makes it look like I wrote it. If you have another question, ask it as a separate question.

Comment: sorry @SeanB.Durkin for the inconvience