# Inset xslt missing element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a query in the xml and xslt

The below is the Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<Employer>
<Employees>
    <EmployeesDetails>van ind 26%</EmployeesDetails>
</Employees>    
<Employees>
    <EmployeesDetails>van ind</EmployeesDetails>
</Employees>
```

The below is my output file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employer>
<Employees>
    <Names>van</Names>
    <Location>ind</Location>                
    <Weather>26</Weather>
</Employees>
<Employees>
    <Names>van</Names>
    <Location>ind</Location>
    <Weather>100</Weather>
</Employees>
```

In XSLT I need to check(XSL:IF)whether weather element is available or not from Input XML if available(26%) I have to remove % using XSLT then output will be 26. If there Is no element in XML(weather) It has to create by default 100.

Can we able to do this in XSLT is that possible.

Can anyone help me out here please

Comment: Maha, your question is identical to the one you asked before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375172/how-to-insert-a-missing-element-or-modify-an-existing-element/11375597#11375597), where you were already given the perfect answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the following XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EmployeesDetails">
        <xsl:variable name="Detail" select="concat(., ' ')" />
        <xsl:variable name="Names" select="substring-before($Detail, ' ')" />
        <xsl:variable name="Location" select="substring-before(substring-after($Detail, concat($Names, ' ')), ' ')" />
        <xsl:variable name="Weather" select="substring-before(substring-after($Detail, concat($Location, ' ')), '% ')" />
        <Names>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Names" />
        </Names>
        <Location>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Location" />
        </Location>
        <Weather>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($Weather) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Weather" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>100</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Weather>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://www.xmlplayground.com/Gg5F3z