# condition checking in xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Input XML

```
<Employer>
     <Employeedetail>Sam SR Engineer 10%</ Employeedetail >
     <Employeedetail>Sam SR 10%</ Employeedetail >
     <Employeedetail>Sam SR</ Employeedetail >
</ Employer >
```

Below is the Output Input XML

```
<Employer>
 < Employeedetails >
  < Employeedetail1>
    < Employeedetail >
       <Name>Sam</ Name >
       <Grade> SR Engineer </ Grade >
       <Experience>10</ Experience >
    </ Employeedetail >
  </ Employeedetail1>
 </ Employeedetails>
</ Employer >

 <Employer>
 < Employeedetails >
  < Employeedetail1>
    < Employeedetail >
       <Name>Sam</ Name >
       <Grade>SR</ Grade >
       <Experience>10</ Experience >
    </ Employeedetail >
  </ Employeedetail1>
 </ Employeedetails>
</ Employer >

 <Employer>
 < Employeedetails >
  < Employeedetail1>
    < Employeedetail >
       <Name>Sam</ Name >
       <Grade>SR</ Grade >
       <Experience>10</ Experience >
    </ Employeedetail >
  </ Employeedetail1>
 </ Employeedetails>
</ Employer >
```

People from stack overflow they have helped if we have three space sperated node we will get the output

But here there is a slight twist again if you look into the grade Sr Engineer this will come into the grade but the code what I have will display SR into the Grade element and Engineer and 10 (Experience) will come in the Experience element.

If there is no value for Experience it has take by default 10.

In the above Input XML there will be number of Employee details it will come.

[Here is the link for that xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388891/inset-xslt-missing-element#comment15015103_11388891)

Please help for the above question

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look into `xsl:analyze-string` http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string e.g. along the lines of

```
<xsl:template match="Employeedetail">
 <Employeedetail>
  <xsl:analyze-string="." regex="(\w+)\s+(\w+(\s\w+)?)\s+(\d+)">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
       <Name><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></Name>
       <Grade><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></Grade>
       <Experience><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(4)"/></Experience>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
 </Employeedetail>
</xsl:template>
```

Untested but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: hi @Martin actually i want in XSLT 1.0 is that possible to do in xslt1.0

Comment: If you don't want an XSLT 2.0 answer then don't tag the question with "XSLT 2.0".

Comment: Sorry, maha, `analyze-string` is new in XSLT 2.0. Please don't tag questions as xslt-2.0 if you are looking for an XSLT 1.0 solution. As for an XSLT 2.0 approach, which XSLT 1.0 processor do you use? Does it support http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Maha, I suggest you google on XSLT 1.0 string functions. This sort of problem is really trivial enough that you shouldn't be posting in StackOverflow. Yes, you may be a beginner, but that doesn't stop you from using google.

Here is a couple of starting points for you:

1. Look at http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp
2. In relation to your particular question, consider functions string-before() and string-after()

Comment: B Durkin I was searching for this in google. I did not understand how it will come and i am novice in XSLT and XML.

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Employeedetail">
  <xsl:variable name="vExp" select=
   "substring(., string-length()-2, 2)"/>
     <Employer>
      <Employeedetails>
        <Employeedetail1>
            <Employeedetail>
             <name><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' ')"/></name>
             <grade>
               <xsl:value-of select=
               "substring-before(substring-after(., ' '), $vExp)"/>
             </grade>
             <experience><xsl:value-of select="$vExp"/></experience>
            </Employeedetail>
        </Employeedetail1>
      </Employeedetails>
     </Employer>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Employer>
    <Employeedetail>Sam SR Engineer 10%</Employeedetail>
</Employer>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Employer>
   <Employeedetails>
      <Employeedetail1>
         <Employeedetail>
            <name>Sam</name>
            <grade>SR Engineer </grade>
            <experience>10</experience>
         </Employeedetail>
      </Employeedetail1>
   </Employeedetails>
</Employer>
```

Comment: hi @Dimitre when i try to run in saxon it says the below message

Warning: at xsl:stylesheet on line 2 column 51 of testing.xsl:
  Running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an xsLT 2.0 processor

Comment: hi @Dimitre how can i edit this question can you please tell me

Comment: @maha: This message means that you are running an XSLT 1.0 transformation with an XSLT 2.0 processor -- nothing to fear about.